# Git add a tracked folder

Tags: git, github

I have 2 folders inside a parent folder.
[image: Here is the image of my current folder]

I initialized git inside server folder (i need it for deployment ) and I would like to create a new github repo containing both server and client folder . But, the server folder is always empty in this repo.

I tried to push the folder "QUIZERO" top github but server folder is empty

Comment: Are you asking how to track _the same files_ in two different repos? (A git repo inside another git repo is a submodule, but that isn’t what is described in the question). Please edit the question to clarify

Comment: `i need it for deployment` I don’t know what this means but I suggest this is both the root of your current difficulties and not a real/hard requirement.

Comment: Git doesn't track folders, only files. Git is also not a deployment tool (though people constantly try to abuse it into that role.)

Comment: You should show the git commands your using (or describe the GIT GUI operations).  "git init" just creates an empty non-bare git repository. Push and pull are operations between bare and non-bare repositories (i.e. local and remote repositories), so what you're saying doesn't make sense unless QUIZERO contains a git repository. You may "git add" files to a git repository.

Comment: Are you thinking about https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-submodule?